# Как вставить текст в SVG фигуру, расположенную под углом?

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Нужно вставить текст в данную фигуру.

```html
<svg width="644" height="242" viewBox="0 0 644 242" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M641 160.576L50.1905 240L2 40.4839L575.385 2L641 160.576Z" fill="#BEC8C9" fill-opacity="0.21" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

Не совсем знаю, как использовать svg. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6):

Текст добавляется с помощью тегов `<text>`, но он по умолчанию идет горизонтально.
`x` и `y` координаты первого символа текста

```html
<svg width="644" height="242" viewBox="0 0 644 242" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid">
   <path d="M641 160.576L50.1905 240L2 40.4839L575.385 2L641 160.576Z" fill="#BEC8C9" fill-opacity="0.21" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" /> 

 <text x="45" y="120" font-size="24px" fill="black" >Многострочный немного длинный Text SVG </text>
 <text x="45" y="160" font-size="24px" fill="black" >Многострочный немного длинный Text SVG </text>

</svg>
```

Поэтому текст надо объединить в одну группу `<g>` с  фигурой и трансформировать их совместно, тогда будет всё ОК.

```html
<svg width="644" height="242" viewBox="0 0 644 242" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid">
 
<g transform="rotate(-15 0 55)  skewX(7) skewY(10)">
<rect stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  x="0" y="55" width="550" height="180" />
 <text x="45" y="120" font-size="24px" fill="black" >Многострочный немного длинный Text SVG </text>
 <text x="50" y="160" font-size="24px" fill="black" >Многострочный немного длинный Text SVG </text>

</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Решение CSS

Прием тот же, что и в SVG. Текст трансформируется вместе со своим `<div>`

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(45deg);
  background: dodgerblue;
}
div:nth-child(2n) {
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-45deg);
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>Москва 2200 км</div>
<div>Севастополь 3100 км</div>
<div>Витебск 3200 км</div>
<div>Волгоград 2800 км</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно крутить весь SVG документ

**Это гораздо проще - смотрите результат**

```css
.item {
  max-width: 560px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  perspective: 400px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(-20deg)rotateX(-20deg)rotateZ(-10deg)translateX(-15%)scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 640 120">
  <rect width="600" height="100" x="20" y="10" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="#ccc"/>
  <foreignObject x="40" y="20" width="580" height="160">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, tenetur! Quibusdam corporis blanditiis et pariatur! Suscipit voluptas dolorum porro temporibus iste natus. Reprehenderit debitis, totam, iusto eum perferendis vitae ducimus, quisquam reiciendis quidem aut explicabo officia amet? Quibusdam excepturi labore ex dolorem quam illum autem rem nesciunt, eos veniam quod?
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: крутить SVG, на мой взгляд, отнюдь не лучшее решение. Так как при верстке ему в HTML разработчик отведет определенные размеры, пусть хоть в процентах. Но при повороте размер SVG увеличится. Увеличатся белые отступы, на которые никто не рассчитывал заранее.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT разумеется что размеры будут но об этом ни слова в вопросе нету хотя есть и perspectiv-origin + translateZ и куча всяких 3D преобразований